# Mock Umbraco configuration in test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, umbraco

When running unit tests on code using some Umbraco Core extensions, such as `string.ToUrlSegement()`, the following error is thrown:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load the Umbraco.Core.Configuration.UmbracoSettings.IUmbracoSettingsSection from config file, ensure the web.config and umbracoSettings.config files are formatted correctly

How do you prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside copying all Umbraco settings into your test projects app.config, you can add the following configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="umbracoConfiguration">
        <section name="settings" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.UmbracoSettings.UmbracoSettingsSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

This prevents that exception being thrown when using Umbraco core functions dependent on configuration of a main project.

Discovered this and some other great tips [here](http://skrift.io/articles/archive/unit-testing-umbraco-plausible/).